# Copy Files Between Windows Servers with Java?

Tags: java

I'm looking for code, or a library, which I can use to copy files between Windows servers using Java.  Picture a primary server that runs a background thread, so that whenever a transaction is completed, it backs up the database files to the backup server.  (This is required protocol, so no need to discuss the pros/cons of this action). In other words, transaction completes, Java code gets executed which copies one directory to the back-up server.

The way the Windows machines are set up, the primary server has the back-up server's C: drive mapped as it's own Z: drive.  Both machines running Windows 2003 or 2008 Server.  Java 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the correct answer on another forum and from messing around a little with the settings.  The problem with copying files from one machine to another in Windows (using either a .bat file or using straight-up Java code) is the user permissions.  On the primary server, you MUST set the Tomcat process to run as the administrator, using that administrator's username and password.  (Right-click on the Tomcat service, select "Log On" tab, enter administrator's username/password).  The default user that Tomcat runs on (local user), isn't sufficient to copy files between networked drives on Windows.  When I set that correctly, both the .bat file solution I had tried previous to this post, and a straight-Java solution suggested here worked just fine.

Hope that helps someone else, and thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Note that this doesn't answer the concrete question as stated in the question message. It only answers the undelying problem which made you to ask the question as it now is (and which nobody of us has any notion of while you posted the original question).

Comment: When have you ever had a "concrete problem" in programming?  There's always lots of variables to any problem, some known, some unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the files by [`File#listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) on a directory from one disk, iterate over each of them, create a new `File` on the other disk, read from a `FileInputStream` from the file from one disk and write it to a `FileOutputStream` on the file on the other disk.

In a nut:

```
for (File file : new File("C:/path/to/files").listFiles()) {
    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
        File destination = new File("Z:/path/to/files", file.getName());
        // Do the usual read InputStream, write OutputStream job here.
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [Java IO tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/)

---

By the way, if you were using Java 7, you would have used [`Path#copyTo()`](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Path.html#copyTo%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) for this.

```
Paths.get("C:/path/to/files").copyTo(Paths.get("Z:/path/to/files"));
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work across multiple Windows machines?  I seem to remember trying this and it working fine between different drives on the same machine, but not across different machines.  Though I didn't try your exact code.

Comment: Java 7?  Isn't that just a myth?

Comment: You told that the other disk was mapped. This is fully transparent to Java. Any potential issues would be platform related, e.g. read/write permissions and so on.

Comment: It is mapped.  I think there's some permission elements involved though, depends on the username running the Java process.  I'm hoping to get around that issue.

Comment: Agreed with BalusC. As long as you have the permissions to the disk that is mapped you should just be able to use the io classes to write the files there.
However, if you absolutely couldn't do it...I supposed you could have your Java code kick off a .bat file that would do the file copy.
But using the i/o classes would probably be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend using [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) for this.

The [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class provides methods to iterate over directories and copy files from one directory to another. You don't have to worry about reading and writing files yourself because it's all done by the library for you.